# Loading dynamic content for offline downloaded website

Tags: dynamic

I have a question about loading dynamic content for an offline website version saved via a browser (like Google Chrome). For the website: [link](https://live.itftennis.com/en/live-scores/), is it possible to replicate dynamic content loading, specifically the statistics calculation, so that the offline version looks the same as the online website? Does the statistics calculation for the online website occur directly on the website or a server? And can this be substituted for offline use?